# Own maven plugin with nested complex objects and default values

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

while developing some of my maven-plugins, I came upon the idea to have a more structured way to provide configurations, but I'm not sure there is a way which works.

Is it possible to have a MOJO, that has instances from `BaseSettings` and `MavenSettings` used in this way, or am I forced to "polute" these fields directly into my MOJOs?

```java
import org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractMojo;
import org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.Parameter;

public abstract class SomeSpecialAbstractMojo extends AbstractMojo{

    @Parameter
    protected BaseSettings baseSettings = new BaseSettings();

    @Parameter
    protected MavenSettings mavenSettings = new MavenSettings();
}
```

-

```java
import org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.Component;
import org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.Parameter;
import org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject;
import org.apache.maven.project.MavenProjectHelper;

public class MavenSettings {

    @Parameter(name = "project", property = "project", readonly = true, required = true)
    protected MavenProject project;

    @Component
    protected MavenProjectHelper projectHelper;
}
```

-

```java
import org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.Parameter;

public class BaseSettings {

    @Parameter(name = "skip", defaultValue = "false")
    protected boolean skip = false;

    @Parameter(name="verbose", defaultValue = "true")
    protected boolean verbose = true;
}
```

The idea was to have some generic properties bundled into their own "space", which makes my MOJOs smaller, and my code more structured.

**EDIT:**
I want to have this kind of execution-configuration:

```xml
<configuration>
    <baseSettings>
        <verbose>true</verbose>
    </baseSettings>
    <!-- mavenSettings is omitted, I want to "auto-use-default" here -->
    <otherComplexSettings>
        <complexValue1>value1</complexValue1>
    </otherComplexSettings>
</configuration>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>goal1-call</id>
        <goals>
            <goal>mojo1</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <otherComplexSettings>
                <complexValue1>override-value1</complexValue1>
            </otherComplexSettings>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
    <execution>
        <id>goal2-call</id>
        <goals>
            <goal>mojo2</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <!-- only part of mojo2 -->
            <anotherComplexSettings>
                <complexValue3>value3</complexValue3>
            </anotherComplexSettings>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
    <execution>
        <id>goal3-call</id>
        <goals>
            <goal>mojo3</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <otherComplexSettings>
                <complexValue1>override-value012</complexValue1>
            </otherComplexSettings>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
    <execution>
        <id>goal4-call</id>
        <goals>
            <goal>mojo4</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

Comment: What do you mean by more structured way of configuration?

Comment: @khmarbaise As posted with my example-code. I want to have `<baseSettings>` available inside each MOJO (I need to create multiple), because they need to share a lot of parameters, this was an idea to minify code-duplication (and making it more readable)

Comment: There might be no solution to my problem, because I would highly depend on `@Parameter`-annotations within the complex object, which is not supported: http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/why-the-defaultValue-is-not-being-injected-in-Parameter-inside-a-complex-parameter-bean-tp5835732p5835735.html

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that answers your question, but you can use your own POJOs as parameters. Here is an [example](https://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html#other-object-classes). You may also use properties or maps.